# I'm looking for an idiomatic expression meaning 'that old problem'

Tags: idiom-requests

It's on the tip of my tongue but I can't think of the expression referring to a repeated problem that gets verbalised; something like 'that old nugget'??!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you're thinking of *old chestnut*.

Comment: "Old chestnut" would be more apt for jokes or aphorisms than for problems.

Comment: Not necessarily, in my experience. The OED's definition begins, true enouigh, ‘a story that has been told before, a “venerable” joke’, but continues ‘hence, in extended use, anything trite, stale, or too often repeated.’

Comment: Another way to indicate idiomatically that something is a recurring problem is to frame the description as "There's X, rearing its ugly head again."